# Build job oversubversion using jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins

I am setting up jenkins in my ubuntu system.I also have an ec2 instance to deploy projects. I also have an local svn repository. I can able to build job from git and pushig the builds to my ftp server(ec2). But i can't build job from local svn to ftp server. When i build the job shows the below error:

> Running as SYSTEM Building in workspace
>   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jenkins_testing2 Updating
>   https://192.168.1.11/svn/fieldpro_v2/trunk at revision
>   '2019-08-22T14:21:10.694 +0530' --quiet Using sole credentials
>   senthil/****** in realm ‘https://192.168.1.11:443 VisualSVN Server’
>   At revision 34
>
> No changes for https://192.168.1.11/svn/fieldpro_v2/trunk since the
>   previous build [jenkins_testing2] $ /bin/sh -xe
>   /tmp/jenkins5601385509024889778.sh
>   + svn commit http://3.210.139.33/jenkins_testing/ svn: E205000: Try 'svn help commit' for more information svn: E205000: Commit targets
>   must be local paths svn: E205000:
>   'http://3.210.139.33/jenkins_testing' is not a local path Build step
>   'Execute shell' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE